# Uncaught Reference Input is not defined- @Input() not working in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-inputs

I am a newbie trying to learn Angular2 from ng-book 2(v49). Here are the contents of article.componenets.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Article } from './article.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article',
  templateUrl: './article.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./article.component.css'],
 host: {
 class: 'row'
 }
})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() article: Article;



  voteUp(): boolean {
    this.article.voteUp();
    return false;
  }

  voteDown(): boolean {
    this.article.voteDown();
    return false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is the error on the angular-cli:

```
ERROR in C:/Users/saad/Desktop/books/Angular JS2/angular2Reddit/src/app/article/article.component.ts (13,4): Cannot find name 'Input'.)
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

[image: Console Error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing import for the Input directive, so change the first line as

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

It is good practice to have the @Input parameters with some value else you will end up getting **Unhandled promise error** some where in your application.

For that it can be defined inside your **ngOnInit** or **constructor**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.article={
         id: 0
         .....
   };
}
```

or

```
constructor(....) {
   this.article={
         id: 0,
         .....
   };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Fixed my Issue. Although no such thing was mentioned in the book.

Answer (score 5):

You have to import Input if you want to use it :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
```