# How to pass data from one component to other in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have my login controller where i login and on success I get data to be displayed on home page. How do i pass this data to home component?

this is the function in login Component

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.returnUrl = '/home';
  }
  doLogin(event) {
   // console.log(event);
   // console.log(this.loginForm.value);
   this.authenticationService.login(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password)
   .subscribe(
   (response) => {
    console.log(response);
   if(response.authenticateResult==0){
    sessionStorage.setItem('user_token', response.user_token);
   console.log(response.project_list.projects);
    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    }else{
this.error = 'Please enter correct Username and password';
    }
   }
   )
  }
```

response.project_list.projects has list of projects which I want to display in home page. I am new to angular 2 . So I am not understanding how i can get access to the data which is in login component. Is there any way to access data from 1 component to other and process it according to that particular component?

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738974/can-i-emmit-the-event-from-parent-to-child-in-angular2 to send data also.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this approach.

Comment: There are a lot of posts. You can use [**Input**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320402/input-not-working-in-angular-2/42320582#42320582) & [**localStorage**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603319/how-to-store-an-object-of-a-class-type-in-browsers-storage-and-retrieve-it/42603514#42603514) click on the links Happy coding :)

Comment: You can also go to the [Angular website](https://angular.io) where they have "recipes" for tackling common problems like this

Comment: Yeah. I checked local storage, but in case there third part cookies are blocked it doesn't work. Is there any alternate for local storage like rootscope or something like in angular js?

Comment: @MendonAshwini asking me ? something?

Comment: @Aravind yes. About local storage. As i find using local storage may create problem in case third party cookies are blocked

Comment: yeah . I think sharing data with Service will solve the localstorage problem too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use [services](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) to share data between components. You can create something like following

```
// replace any to your actual projects type
@Injectable()
export class ProjectsService {
    public setProjects(projects: any) {
        this._projects = projects;
    }

    public get projects(): any {
        return this._projects;
    }

    private _projects: any = null; //or empty array if projects is an array
}
```

Then you can inject it in both Login and Home components:

```
export class LoginComponent {
    constructor(private projectsService: ProjectsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.returnUrl = '/home';
      }

      doLogin(event) {
       // console.log(event);
       // console.log(this.loginForm.value);
       this.authenticationService.login(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password)
       .subscribe(
       (response) => {
        console.log(response);
       if(response.authenticateResult==0){
        sessionStorage.setItem('user_token', response.user_token);
       console.log(response.project_list.projects);
        this.projectsService.setProjects(response.project_list.projects);
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        }else{
    this.error = 'Please enter correct Username and password';
        }
       }
       )
      }
}

export class HomeComponent {
    constructor(private projectsService: ProjectsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.projectsService.projects);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You can additionally save tour projects in LocalStorage:

```
// replace any to your actual projects type
@Injectable()
export class ProjectsService {
    constructor() {
        const projects: any = localStorage.getItem(this.projectsKey);
        if (projects) {
            this._projects = JSON.parse(projects);
        }
    }
    public setProjects(projects: any) {
        localStorage.setItem(this.projectsKey, JSON.stringify(projects));
        this._projects = projects;
    }

    public get projects(): any {
        return this._projects;
    }

    private _projects: any = null; //or empty array if projects is an array
    private readonly projectsKey: string = 'projects_key';
}
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is we loose the data on page refresh

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can use localStorage to keep your projects between refresh.

Comment: yeah.. got it.. just a query. Now that localstorage can be used from anywhere, whats the use of having a service?

Comment: It encapsulates implementation details. If in future you want to implement another caching functionality you need to update your code in one place instead of looking through entire project to find all the places where you're using localStorage and 'projects_key' constant.

Comment: To add to the use of service, item in localStorage won't be available for another component until you refresh the page, so you can get the value from the service instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, theres a way to do it,and you do this through the Output decorator and EventEmmiter class (both from angular/core).
For example, in one of my projects I use select2 for Angular, wich tells me the actual selected value through the output "valueChanged", then I made a "event handler" wich will be executed everytime "valueChanged" event is executed. This event handler is also an output event itself, and will be executed just after valueChanged, and I do this to pass data to the parent component. You can repeat this approach all the times you need. Here is my code

ts:

```
import { Output, EventEmitter, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select2item',
  templateUrl: './select2item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select2item.component.css']
})
export class Select2itemComponent implements OnInit {

    private select2options:S2options;
  private selected:string;
  @Output()//this is how you declare a custom "output event"
  selectedItem = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.select2options = {};
    this.select2options.ajax={
        url:"/item/ajax",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: (term)=>{ //console.log(term.term);
        return {sku:term.term}; 
      },
        delay:1000,
        processResults: (data)=>{
            console.log(data);
            return {
                results:data.map((item)=>{
                    return {id:item.id, text:item.name};
                })
            }
        }
    };

  }
//and this is where you define your custom "output event"
  public currentItem(e:any){
    this.selected=e.value;
    this.selectedItem.emit(this.selected);
  }

}
```

html:

```
<select2 [options]="select2options" 
(valueChanged)="currentItem($event)"></select2>
```

take a look to this quick tutorial, it will help you (its made by Ionic team):

[Angular Outputs](http://learnangular2.com/outputs/)