# Angular 4 get properties from class

Tags: angular, typescript

In my typescript file I have a code like this:

```
searchByID(_byid: ByID) {
    // new instance of the Order model
    this.order = new Order();
    this._httpService.post(this.apiBaseURL + this.api + '/SolicitudSugerido/ByIdMst', _byid)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.productsResultArray = data,
            this.order.fechahora = this.productsResultArray.fechahora;
            this.order.idsestatus = this.productsResultArray.idsestatus;
            this.order.idestatu = this.productsResultArray.idestatu;
            this.order.abc = this.productsResultArray.abc;
            this.order.guardar = this.productsResultArray.guardar;
            //console.log(this.productsResultArray);
        }
    )
}
```

I have other component where I do this:

```
import { SolicitudComponent } from "./../solicitud/solicitud.component";
```

Then I have this method in the same component:

```
showSolicitudFormWithData() {
    this.sugerido = this._solicitud.order;
    this.fecha = this._solicitud.order.fechahora;
    console.log(this.sugerido);
}
```

So the problem is that this.fecha when I try to see the value at console it says undefined, but this.sugerido prints this:

Order {}
abc: true,
fechahora: "",
guardar: false,
idestatu: "1"

So what I want to know is how can I print in my html component those values, I have tried: {{fecha}}, but it does not print the value.

I want to have access to that object in my view and in my ts file.
For example to get that response in another object then i can iterate its properties one by one. Like:

```
this.order = this._solicitud.order;
this.order.fechahora = this._solicitud.order.fechahora;
this.order.idsestatus = this._solicitud.order.idsestatus;
```

Later if i want to just access one property or use it as parameter for another api call.

Comment: You probably read it before it is set. I can't see the connection in your code though.

Comment: In my constructor i have. constructor(private _solicitud: SolicitudComponent) {}, thats why im using this_solicitud.order; order is a class i have in my solicitudcomponent.ts like this: order: Order; then this.order = new Order();

Comment: Async code, especially calls over the network, take an eternity compared to code executed in the same process. If you make an HTTP request, the calkback passed to `subscribe(...)` will only be executed when the response arrives. In the meantime your other code reads the field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in/36291681#36291681 might give you ideas to connect async code to ensure some order.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer i'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said that the value of your service is fetched by `this.sugerido`, it might be an ansynchronous issue between when the data is set and when you are reading it whith `this.fecha`. You can use directly in your html template the elvis operator who will wait until the value is retrieved before displaying it.

Try this in your html template: `{{sugerido?.fechahora}}` instead of `{{fecha}}`.

If you want to access the data fetch from your server, you can proceed this way:

```js
searchByID(_byid: ByID) { // call the service
    this._httpService.post(this.apiBaseURL + this.api + '/SolicitudSugerido/ByIdMst', _byid)
      .subscribe(data => {
          this.productsResultArray = data;
          // if you want to use this data elsewhere in the component, you can call a function with data as argument
          this.anotherFunction(data)
        },
        error => {
          return <any>error
        });
  }

  anotherFunction(data: any) {
    //process the data send from the server here.
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Comment: @RaulBaez, that is great!

Comment: hey @edkeveked im facing one more issue, i have the order object, and i want to print it to console like this: console.log(this._solicitud.order); and i do see the object with its properties, but when i try to access a single property i see and "undefined" only. console.log(this._solicitud.order.fechahora); how can i achieve this?

Comment: With console.log(this.order) i get the object with its properties, but console.log(JSON.stringify(this.order)) and cosole.log(Object.keys(this.order); i got nothing.

Comment: Could you please post here, what you get with `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.order))`?

Comment: yeah that will output: [], just like that.

Comment: I think my problem is that im trying to access that object which is filled in the .subscribe, but i don't know how to make that work or another alternative to do it.

Comment: Why don't you simply do `this.order=this.productsResultArray` since they share almost all the attributes? Or `this.order=data`?

Comment: Yes i tried that also, but the problem is that they are in different components, different .ts files, well im not sure if thats a problem lol.

Comment: I make it work, but there's still an issue, it works till the second time i get results from the api.

Comment: This is the call: `code` searchByID(_byid: ByID) {
        // call the service
        this._httpService.post(this.apiBaseURL + this.api + '/SolicitudSugerido/ByIdMst', _byid)
        .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.productsResultArray = data;
            },
            error => {
                return <any>error
            },
            () => {
                return this.productsResultArray;
            },
        );
    }

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a recommended solution to add a component via DI(in the constructor) and then get the value. You will not know when the value is returned. In order to give a better answer more structure or understanding of the code is needed.

If you have more than one component on the same screen then you can use events and setup a container component which handles those events across the components. Have a look at the following to get an understanding:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/

The second scenario is if one component is try to pass a value which the other component wants to subscribe on another route. In such a scenario you would want to use the local storage to store the value and the second component has an observable setup on that value. So whenever a change happens it is rendered. The following link will be helpful in that scenario:
[How to pass data from one component to other in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801566/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-other-in-angular-2)

The ideal solution however is to use an application State. There is a module called ngrx for Angular which is basically the implementation Redux. Read the following link to get an understanding of that:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/state-management/ngrx/